How to specify which schema i want to use using Langchain's SQLDatabase.from_uri?
Im trying to use SQLDatabase.from_uri from Langchain but im not sure where to specify which schema i want to get the tables.
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}")
print(db.dialect)
print(db.get_usable_table_names())
print(db.table_info)

If I do this it connects correctly to the database but its blank when printing that get usable names method, I guess that is because there are multiple schemas on this database and therefore I need to find a way to specify that schema.

Not familiar with Langchain or Python, but in Postgresql schema is defined via search_path setting. The default is: "$user", public - looks first at schema with same name as user then public schema
it can be redefined via SET search_path TO myschema,public;
details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html
